# how to make custom templatetags discoverable in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I wanted to make my custom template tag and I followed the steps given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). It is said that I need to store my templatetags in a directory of an app. So I created a new app, put the templatetags there and included the app in `installed APPS`.

But when I try to `load` the template tag in my template, I get the following error:

```
'generic_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library generic_tags not found,
```

And when I see the directories in which it searched for, the templatetags library for for my app is not there. It means it is not searching for template tags in apps created by me. Do I need to add anything in my `settings.py` file also?

My templatetag definition file is

```
import datetime

from django import template
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ungettext

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='timesince_human')
def humanize_timesince(date):
    if not date:
        return

    delta = datetime.datetime.now() - date

    num_years = delta.days / 365
    if (num_years > 0):
        return ungettext(u"%d year ago", u"%d years ago", num_years) % num_years

    num_weeks = delta.days / 7
    if (num_weeks > 0):
        return ungettext(u"%d week ago", u"%d weeks ago", num_weeks) % num_weeks

    if (delta.days > 0):
        return ungettext(u"%d day ago", u"%d days ago", delta.days) % delta.days

    num_hours = delta.seconds / 3600
    if (num_hours > 0):
        return ungettext(u"%d hour ago", u"%d hours ago", num_hours) % num_hours

    num_minutes = delta.seconds / 60
    if (num_minutes > 0):
        return ungettext(u"%d minute ago", u"%d minutes ago", num_minutes) % num_minutes

    return ungettext(u"%d second ago", u"%d seconds ago", delta.seconds) % delta.seconds
```

and it has been stored in `templatetag` directory of an app named `utilityapp` and I have also included the `__init__.py` file

Comment: the directory is `templatetags` not `templatetag`

Answer (score 0):

Your create

```
__init__.py
```

in templatetags directory? Exec

```
register = template.Library()
```

in you file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `register = template.Library()` **before** your templatetag definition. If it is after it won't work. Also make sure **init**.py is present in the templatetag directory and check the rest of the error output to see if there is anything else useful.

Comment: Yes I have done both the things... I have added my templatetag definition file